# How can I set the cell margins in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables)

How can I set (modify the default values) the internal, i.e., top/bottom/left/right, cell margins in a `table`?

Comment: If you're referring to column/cell padding, then see [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764). Let us know by giving some feedback whether the link provides an answer or not.

Comment: it worked as expected, by simply using the command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}` for vertical padding. The rule for horizontal padding might work as well.

Comment: @Werner I couldnt figure out how to set the padding for a specific row. All commands suggested in the dup leads to the application of padding rules for the whole table. But, I mean, I'd like to have a table with different padding values, depending on the cell.